# Как вытащить не только текст, но и ссылки javascript

Tags: javascript

Методом гугления(с js только начинаю знакомство) сделал для своих нужд скриптик.
Идея в том, что по указанным селекторам я вытаскиваю со страницы список.
Однако, вытащить этот список со ссылками у меня не вышло, сколько не бился.

Вот скрипт :

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll('li > a'); 
for(var i=0; i< element.length;i++) { 
document.write(element[i].innerHTML + '<br>'); 
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы вместе с текстом вытаскивались ссылки? Или хотя бы список ссылок отдельно?
Спасибо

Comment: `outerHTML` мб вас интересует, а не `inner` ? или значение атрибута `.href` ?

Answer (score 2):

если рассмотреть ссылку

```
<a href="#"><span>xxx</span>yyy</a>
```

то, извлекая значение `innerHTML` вы будете получать вложенный контент ссылки, то есть `<span>xxx</span>yyy`. Вы же, вероятно, хотите получить всю данную строку целиком. Для этого можете использовать значение `outerHTML`.

Или же вам требуется получить значение атрибута `href`, которое в рассматриваемом примере будет равно `#`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вариант с outer подходит для решения моей задачи.
Но получение атрибута .href тоже хотел бы узнать(изначально интересно было именно его получение). Если не затруднит - опишите.
Еще раз спасибо

Comment: @ptpwork дак `element[i].href`

Comment: Логично) Спасибо

Comment: @ptpwork пожалуйста. Можете ткнуть галку у ответа слева.